# How to check decimal in ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, decimal

I downloaded a project from site. It contains a method called find.

```
   def find(value)

      if value == :decimal
       return true

      else
       return false
      end

  end
```

I tried with so many values but the condition is not matching. Could you please explain the purpose of value == :decimal??

Comment: try running `git grep ':decimal'` - probably this is defined value elsewhere in the application

Comment: yes @dax . it's defined in a .yml file thanks

Comment: Judging from the code, I can tell that it is not professionally written. It is unreliable.

Comment: Somebody who knows even the slightest bit about programming would write this: `def find(value) value == :decimal end`.

Comment: ...and probably not name it 'find'.

Answer (score 2):

This method returns `true` if `value` is the symbol `:decimal`, otherwise return `false`.

```
find(:decimal) # true
```

Test whether `value` is symbol `:decimal` is the only purpose.

Comment: yes @xdazz . It's :decimal only. it was assigned in a .yml file.